# Java 8 - Providing raw type argument to a method expecting generic type causes its return type to be erased

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Following example compiles successfully in Java 7 and fails to compile in Java 8 (and newer).

```
public abstract class Example<T> 
{
    public T method() 
    {
        return method(new HashMap());
    }

    abstract T method(Map<String, String> arg);
}
```

Java 7:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

Java 8:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\dev\projects\Java8\src\main\java\example\Example.java:10: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to T
        return method(new HashMap());
                     ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Example
```

Error above means that `method(new HashMap())` returned `Object` instead of expected `T`.

To avoid this error in Java 8, I have to provide generic type argument i.e. change `new HashMap()` to `new HashMap<>()`.

The disturbing part is that error caused by raw type argument passed to `method(Map<String, String>)` is actually about this method returning `Object` instead of `T`. So I can expect:

```
T result = method(new HashMap<>());
```

..., but:

```
Object result = method(new HashMap());
```

It doesn't seem to be intuitive behavior that parametrized type of method return is suddenly forgotten if non-generic type argument is provided where generic type argument is expected. It's just a *context of argument* in method definition that I'd expect to be isolated from *context of return type* in the same method's definition.

Is there a justification and applicable explanation for such behavior? I am aware of changes affecting generics done in Java 8, but nothing matching this specific case.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: this surely looks like a bug in 7, fixed in 8. And also *compiler doesn't complain about raw type HashMap* - it does, via a warning

Comment: Ok, I hope I have clarified that section to point on error and not indicate any statements related to warnings.

Comment: thing is - once you have used raw types - everything else is the erasure types of generics. I am scanning through the JLS for the exact words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JLS, Chapter 15.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html)

> 15.12.2.6. Method Result and Throws Types
>
> The result type of the chosen method is determined as follows:
>
> [...] if unchecked conversion was necessary for the method to be
>   applicable, then the result type is the erasure (§4.6) of the method's
>   declared return type. [...]

It got raised in [JDK-6791481](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6791481).

If I would make it `public abstract class Example<T extends java.lang.Exception>`, then I would get `error: incompatible types: Exception cannot be converted to T`.

---

(Again it seems that I have to fail to find an answer for a day, elaborate a long question, post it and find the answer shortly after.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't really find the issue for java-7 (I'll try more), but it seems that this is specified [in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) via:

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

I *think* it's this one, since I can't find anything under raw types that would better explain it. Or, in simple words, once you use raw types, everything else (even un-related stuff) will use erasure types as-well.

Comment: Thanks for this finding. Actually I have found the issue. Same behavior is mentioned also in another section of JLS defining method result types. Please take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @CodeSculptor nice! you are free to accept your own answer btw in a few days